# paypal Payments Pro Hosted Solution Integration repeat payment

Tags: button, iframe, paypal, solution, hosted

I am using paypal express checkout where i can create take payment for an order with multiple recurring payment profiles in it. e.g. initial payment £5, item A £3 every month, item B £5 every year.

I am asked to implement this using website payments pro hosted solution using iframe API now.
But i can't figure out how to pass this order to it.
According to Integration guide I need to use Button Manager API and create a template= templateD button type, but that button type only accept one profile.

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_GB/developer/docs/pdf/hostedsolution_uk.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot create a recurring profile through the Hosted Payments endpoint by passing "Payments Standards" variables.

The PayPal system will automatically do a 302 redirect to the webscr endpoint (if the browser were to load the page outside of the iframe, with X-Frame-Options set, it refuses to load at all).

You cannot create recurring payments profiles through HSS (hosted sole solution). This product will merely take credit card payments from your site.